Is there a way to create a schema for this column?
I am working with a Parquet file that contains a complicated nested column structure. Specifically, I have a column where the structure is as follows:
 {
   "dynamodb": {
      "NewImage": {
         "DiscountData": {
            "M": {
               "TEST1": {"N": "0"},
               "TEST2": {"N": "0"},
               "TEST3": {"N": "0"},
               "TEST4": {"N": "0"},
               "TEST5": {"N": "1"}
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

The key challenge is the M field. It is dynamic: it can contain varying keys (TEST1, TEST2, etc.) depending on the dataset. I am processing multiple Parquet files, and the structure of M may change across files.
I attempted to use the option to infer the schema , but I am having this issue:
AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema 

To make it consistent, I want to:
Treat the entire content of M as a string (e.g., JSON string), or Convert M into a MapType where keys and values are strings.
Here’s the schema I tried to define:
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, MapType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("dynamodb", StructType([
        StructField("NewImage", StructType([
            StructField("DiscountData", StructType([
                StructField("M", MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)
            ]), True)
        ]), True)
    ]), True)
])

This is what i am using to create the dataframe:
df_disscountcoderule = spark.read \
    .schema(schema) \
    .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
    .parquet(f"s3://{source_bucket}/{source_discountcodesrules_prefix}")\
    .filter(input_file_name().endswith(".parquet"))\
    .filter(~input_file_name().contains("processing-failed"))

However, I get the following error when applying this schema:
ava.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType cannot be cast to class org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType (org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType and org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

My Questions:
Is there a way to create a static schema that can handle this dynamic structure?
How can I convert the M field into a JSON string or a MapType for consistent processing?
I appreciate any guidance or alternative approaches!

can you add the schema of parquet file here?

It IS possible to tell spark to interpret type of M to be MapType(str, str) instead of StructType(TEST1, TEST2, ...). But given your source is parquet (strongly typed), I wonder if what you're ending up doing is conversion (from parquet schema to your schema) instead of interpretation (e.g. json/csv text to your schema). --- E.g. spark.read.json('in.json', schema=StructType([StructField('DiscountData', StructType([StructField('M', MapType(StringType(), StringType()))]))])).show() will work if in.json contained {"DiscountData": {"M": {"TEST11": {"N": "0"}, "TEST12": {"N": "0"}} }}

are you sure for the structure for M ? I would replace StructField("M", MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True) with StructField("M", MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType())), True)
